# How to make a subclass of a class template a class template?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <class K, class V>
class A {
   class B;


};

template <class K, class V>
class A<K,V>::B {
     //other things
};
```

which gives me the error
error: ‘B’ is not a class template.
I am working on something that needs B to be a class template on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring `B` as a non-template class member (of the class template `A`).

If you want to make `A::B` a [member template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_template), you should

```
template <class K, class V>
class A {
    template <class T>
    class B;
};

template <class K, class V> // for the enclosing class template
template <class T>          // for the member template
class A<K,V>::B {
     //other things
};
```

Comment: Sweet! This solved my problem. SO its called a member template?

Comment: @Milan Yes, including member class, function, variable, they can all be declared as template.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `<K ,V>` after `B`. B itself is not declared as template, right?

Comment: Thats right B itself is not a template. I put <K, V> with B just to see if it forces B to be a class template but it doesn't.

Comment: That is my question, how to define B as template?

Answer (score 0):

It follows the usual rules. That is to say,

```
template <class K, class V>
class A : B<K ,V> {
     //other things
};
```

Single `:`, not double. It's not a specialization but a regular class template so it's just `class A`

Comment: doesn't a single : imply inheritance? Now I am getting class A redefinition error.

Comment: @Milan: subclass/superclass is another common term for derived and base classes, so yes - this is inheritance. But from your accepted answer it's clear that you didn't want a subclass.